# How can I edit an Array from Main Activity with the data and button click from another Activity without switching between Activities?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I tried to initialize a custom array in Main Activity. I want to update/edit the element in array from another activity which contains the data and button click. My main activity is **Main Activity** and my second activity is **Display**. Can anyone help?

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public Pets[] arrayList=new Pets[]{
        new Pets(R.drawable.dog,"Dog","Wolf","The dog is a domesticated descendant of the wolf. Also called the domestic dog"),
        new Pets(R.drawable.bird,"Bird","Unknown!","Birds are a group of warm-blooded vertebrates constituting the class Aves characterised by feathers, toothless beaked jaws"),
        new Pets(R.drawable.cat,"Cat","Tiger","The cat is a domestic species of small carnivorous mammal"),
};
```

```
public class Pets {
    private int mPetImage;

    private String mPetName;

    private String mPetFam;

    private String mDesc;

    public Pets(int PetImage,String PetName,String PetFam,String Desc) {
        this.mPetImage = PetImage;
        this.mPetName = PetName;
        this.mPetFam = PetFam;
        this.mDesc = Desc;
    }

    public int getmPetImage() {
        return mPetImage;
    }

    public Pets setmPetImage(int mPetImage) {
        this.mPetImage = mPetImage;
        return this;
    }

    public String getmPetName() {
        return mPetName;
    }

    public Pets setmPetName(String mPetName) {
        this.mPetName = mPetName;
        return this;
    }

    public String getmPetFam() {
        return mPetFam;
    }

    public Pets setmPetFam(String mPetFam) {
        this.mPetFam = mPetFam;
        return this;
    }

    public String getmDesc() {
        return mDesc;
    }

    public Pets setmDesc(String mDesc) {
        this.mDesc = mDesc;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use your Array as public static, then your edited in the activity you want after getting your Data

Comment: use interface and call backs

Comment: Seeing your code and reequipments, I believe [onActivityResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) will be better approach here

Comment: You should consider an Activity or Fragment to only be a temporary view to some more persistent data source (e.g. a singleton, database, shared preferences, etc). The activity can be destroyed and recreated (and the data lost) by something as simple as the user rotating their screen.

Comment: I tried **Singleton** still it's like copying the array and implementing a copy of the array, my task is not to use **Database**. Can you Share me how **Shared Preferences** works?

Comment: @TylerV Thank you for your advice, Shared Preferences saved my day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Display Activity** after get data to be changed in the array. **Shared Preferences** can be used.

```
SharedPreferences share=getSharedPreferences("myArray",MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor=share.edit();
            editor.putString("desc",textd);
            editor.putInt("pos",pos);
            editor.putInt("click",click);
            editor.apply();
```

To make changes in the Activity where the array is present

```
 SharedPreferences share=getSharedPreferences("myArray",MODE_PRIVATE);
            pos=share.getInt("pos",0);
            text=share.getString("desc","");
            arrayList[pos]=text;
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all do not create data inside the MainActivity. Activity is your view, if you separate your data source from view you can update it very easily.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried that method. But it says like illegal expression declared. is there there anyway that I can initialize in a custom java Class and carry on with my task? I'm using Android Studio right now. If yes,can you Show me the code?